# How to save multiple images using QFileDialog and boost

Tags: c++, boost, qt5, qfiledialog

I have small gui that has N.1 `QGraphicsView` and N.1 `QPushButton`.
After I upload some images I am saving them in a specific folder on my Desktop. For this operation I am combining `QFileDialog` together with the library `boost`. 
Program runs but images are not being saved in the targeted folder, what am I missing?

See below the snipped of code I am using for the save `QPushButton`:

```
void MainWindow::on_saveToFileBtnCamB_clicked()
{
    QString rectB = QFileDialog::getExistingDirectory(this, tr("Choose an image directory to load"),
                                                     fileCamRectB, QFileDialog::ShowDirsOnly | QFileDialog::DontResolveSymlinks);
    boost::filesystem::path pb(rectB.toStdString());
    for(int i=0;i<finishedImages.size();i++)
    {
        finishedImages[i].getB().setSavePath(pb);
        finishedImages[i].getB().save();
        ui->progressBarSaveB->setValue(i);
    }
    dirB.setPath(rectB);
    ui->progressBarSaveB->setValue(finishedImages.size());
    finishedImages.clear();
}
```

Comment: Should it be something like  `finishedImages[i].getB().setSavePath(pb / ("imge_" + std::to_string(i) + ".extention");` ?

Comment: What is `finishedImages[i].getB()` ?

Comment: `private` member

Comment: `QList<StereoImage> finishedImages`

Comment: I tried the following but it does not work yet:         `finishedImages[i].getB().setSavePath(pb / ("imge_" + std::to_string(i) + ".tiff"));`

Comment: `StereoImage` seems not be part of Qt. Do you succeed to save one `StereoImage` ?

Comment: `StereoImage` is a class that is part of a library I have. Images are succesfully loaded and rectified but I am not able to save them yet

Comment: hi Jarod42, just to let you know that your suggestion worked. The program compiles. If you can add your previous solution with the code I can mark your answer as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following my question the correct answer was the initial answer that Jarod42 gave, I was copying and paste wrong:

```
finishedImages[i].getB().setSavePath(pb / ("imge_" + std::to_string(i) + ".extention");
```